# Check and compare two strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, string-matching

I want to check two strings. I want to use the method to check similarity or matching between two strings.

Example:

```
$str1 = "Samsung Galaxy Note 5";
$str2 = "Samsung Galaxy Note5 Black Smartphone";
```

I want the result is match, because both strings have keyword "Samsung Galaxy Note 5".

The other example:

```
$str1 = "Samsung Galaxy Note 4";
$str2 = "Samsung Galaxy Note5 Black Smartphone";
```

The result is not match, because both string don't have same keyword.

What method can I use?

Comment: MySQL code ?? or php??

Comment: How second example not macthes? Samsung Galaxy Matches .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$str1 = "Samsung Galaxy Note 4";
$str2 = "Samsung Galaxy Note5 Black Smartphone";

if(strpos(str_replace(' ', '', $str2), str_replace(' ', '', $str1)) !== 0) {
   echo "Not Matched!";
}
```

For the examples you have provided it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are matching NOTE 5 and NOTE5 so you need to replace space and with the use of `strpos`

```
$str1 = "Samsung Galaxy Note 5";
$str1 = str_replace(" ", "", $str1);
$str2 = "Samsung Galaxy Note 5 Black Smartphone";
$str2 = str_replace(" ", "", $str2);

if (strpos($str2,$str1) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}else{
echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match` along with `preg_replace` like as

```
$str1 = "Samsung Galaxy Note 5";
$str2 = "Samsung Galaxy Note5 Black Smartphone";

if(preg_match("/(".preg_replace('/[\h]/','',$str1).")/i",preg_replace('/[\h]/','',$str2))!==false){
    echo "match";
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/433209)